# Concat string in C++(STL)

Tags: c++, string, stl

i have code like this

```
string xml_path(conf("CONFIG"));

xml_path+=FILE_NAME;
```

Where,
conf function returns `char *` and FILE name is `const char *`

I want to combine it to one line like

```
xml_path(conf("CONFIG")).append(FILE_NAME)
```

how do i do it?

any suggestions ??

Comment: Everyone is missing the fact that you've asked for a one-line solution. (But why do you want that?)

Comment: Suppose i want to concat 5 strings then i can do it .append().append()
I need not to do in 5 steps
its like doing in java 
 StringBuffer obj = new StringBuffer("foobar").append("foo").append("bar");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question asked for one line:

```
string xml_path = string(conf("CONFIG")) + string(FILE_NAME);
```

(I assume `xml_path` is the name of the variable, and not some sort of call in a library I don't know about).

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, if you want to format variable of different type, use a ostringstream.

eg.

```
std::ostringstream oss; 
int a = 2; 
char *s = "sometext"; 
oss<<s<<a<<endl; 
cout<<oss.str(); // will output "sometext2"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const char * f = "foo";
char * b = "bar";

string s = string( f ) + b;
```

Note that you cannot use append(-0 because neither of the strings invvolved is a std:;string. If you really want to append, it will have to be  two-stage process:

```
string s ( f );
s.append( b );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml_path(conf("CONFIG"));
xml_path += string(FILE_NAME);
```

should do the trick.